# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}=?$

Tags: limits, exponentiation

I have a question:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}=?$$

Thanks for your help>

Comment: Factor $3^n$ above and $3^{n+1}$ below.

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $3^n$ to obtain ${(-2/3)^n+1\over 3(-2/3)^{n+1} +3}$.  Note $(-2/3)^n$ has limit zero at infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|-2|<3$ then $(-2)^n=_\infty o(3^n)$ and then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}}=\frac13$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As $n$ goes to $\infty$, what is the ratio of $\large\frac{(-2)^n}{3^n}$. What does this ratio tell you about the importance of the addition?