# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n} $

Tags: limits, exponential-function, exponentiation, infinity

It seems reasonable to assume that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n} $$ goes to zero but I can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: It doesnt go to zero.

Comment: You can find lost of similar question on this site. If you have a look on them, you should be able to solve this problem. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459927/finding-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n1-3n12n3n or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831731/lim-n-to-infty-frac-2n3n-2n13n1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(\frac{2}{3})^n+1} =1.$$Since $\frac{2}{3}<1$ , so $(\frac{2}{3})^n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.